# How to split array of object to individual arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm developing an angular application where I call the following endpoint from CoinGeko API that provides me market charts:

https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=cad&days=7&interval=daily

It returns an like the following:

```
{
    "prices": [
        [
            1643414400000,
            48329.41585141156
        ],
        [
            1643494489000,
            48870.92050262988
        ]
    ],
    "market_caps": [
        [
            1643414400000,
            915485662636.434
        ],
        [
            1643494489000,
            925791491728.014
        ]
    ],
    "total_volumes": [
        [
            1643414400000,
            24532182816.548737
        ],
        [
            1643494489000,
            18070713602.083645
        ]
    ]
}
```

From this response, I need to work on the "prices" property only.

It is an array of arrays with UNIX timestamp and the Crypto price.

So what I'm trying to reach is to have two different arrays where:

- the first one includes only the dates
- second one includes only the prices

The following snippet show my attempt:

**Interfaces.ts**

```
export interface Chart {
    prices:        Array<DatePrice>;
    market_caps:   Array<DatePrice>;
    total_volumes: Array<DatePrice>;
}

export interface DatePrice {
    unixDate: string[];
    price: number[];
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
[...]

coinChart: Chart[];
sevenDayPrices: number[];
sevenDayDates: Date[];

ngOnInit() {
    this._apiService
        .getWeeklyChartData()
        .subscribe(chartData => { 
             this.coinChart = chartData; 
             console.log(chartData);

             chartData.map(x => 
                 x.prices.map(daysPrice => {
                     console.log(daysPrice.price);
                     this.sevenDayPrices = daysPrice.price
                 })
             );
  }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. What I would to achive is something like:

```
sevendayprices = [48329.4158514115, 48870.92050262988]
sevendaydates = [1643414400000, 1643494489000]
```

How can I reach this goal?

~SRJ

Comment: *" it has an array of objects "*: actually its an object with arrays.

Comment: Sure a typo. But prices, market_cap, total_volumes are still arrays of objects.

Comment: its not clear to me what your desired output is in relation to the input.  Doesn't prices already contain arrays of length 2 with price and timestamp?

Comment: *"But prices, market_cap, total_volumes are still arrays of object"*. No, prices, market_cap, total_volumes are arrays of arrays. The whole things is an object where each property is an array of arrays.

Comment: Since the API returns an object, are you sure that you are able to run chartData.map() without errors?

Comment: Ah I think I got it, You want one array containing only the prices and one array only containg the dates. Where each the current pairs are aligned index wise.

Comment: That's right that's exactly what I want. @TheFool

Comment: You go 2 answers showing you how to do it.

Comment: So I'm getting prices, market_cap, total_volumes as arrays of arrays. How can I only get prices array from Object.Values in the response object? Like you're using static data from data variable, is there a way to get
` this._apiService.getWeeklyChartData("bitcoin").subscribe((chartData: Chart[]) => { 
        this.coinChart = chartData;
          
      console.log(this.coinChart);
//here just get the prices array
      Object.values(chartData).forEach(x => console.log(x))`

Comment: You just access the property by name `data.prices`. Data is your decoded API response. `const data = JSON.parse(apiresponse)` or similar. If you look at the statics dat I am using its just like the response from https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=cad&days=7&interval=daily. Only I did not write the other properties since it's not required for the example. It could have 100 more properties, but that would change how I access prices.

Comment: That won't work bc the return type of the API is Chart[], and here's the Chart class. 
`  getWeeklyChartData()
   {
    return this.http.
    get<Chart[]>("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=cad&days=7&interval=daily");
   }
export interface Chart {
 
    prices:        Array<number[]>;
    market_caps:   Array<number[]>;
    total_volumes: Array<number[]>;
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you're doing is pretty much fine. As for the solution, you're receiving Array of arrays, and your Chart interface already contains that. You'd be much better using Array rather than another DatePrice interface bc you don't need it. So first thing first, fix this:

```
//this is wrong
coinChart: Chart[];
//use this instead
coinChart: Chart;
//since you want in readable date, use
sevenDayDates: string[];//instead of date
```

Here goes the easiest logic to split both arrays:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._apiService
        .getWeeklyChartData()
        .subscribe(chartData => { 
             this.coinChart = chartData;
             this.sevenDayDates = this.coinChart.prices.map(function(tuple) {
        return  new Date(tuple[0]).toLocaleTimeString()
          });
          this.sevenDayPrices = this.coinChart.prices.map(function(tuple) {
            return  tuple[1] 
          });
  }
```

Let me know if that works. If your interface is proper, you can literally use all these properties in your chartData response. And I hope in the API call, you're returning Chart type rather than Chart[] type.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Other answers were so complicated! Thank you very much. ~SRJ

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your needed well, the following snippet could do the trick:

```
const response = {
    prices: [
        [
            1643414400000,
            48329.41585141156
        ],
        [
            1643494489000,
            48870.92050262988
        ]
    ],
    market_caps: [
        [
            1643414400000,
            915485662636.434
        ],
        [
            1643494489000,
            925791491728.014
        ]
    ],
    total_volumes: [
        [
            1643414400000,
            24532182816.548737
        ],
        [
            1643494489000,
            18070713602.083645
        ]
    ]
}

...
// Interface
export interface MyObjInterface = {
  prices: string[],
  dates: string[]
}

...
// inside class, above constructor()
myPrices: number[]
obj: MyObjModel



ngOnInit() {
  this.myPrices = response.prices.flat()
  this.obj = {
  prices: this.checkDotInNumber(myPrices, true),
  dates: this.checkDotInNumber(myPrices, false)
}

  console.log(this.obj)
}

checkDotInNumber(arr, hasDot): string[] {
  const a = arr.flat();
  let includeDot = (num) => {
    return num.toString().includes('.')
  }
  
  return (hasDot) ? a.filter(x => includeDot(x)) : a.filter(x => !includeDot(x))
}
```

##Explanation:##

You receive an object as response, so you can access to "prices" property just navigating to "response.prices" (with "response" I refer to my object that is the same that you have in your subscription: chartData).

Having "response.prices" you can do some operation on the array and create a new object that I named "this.obj" with two properties: "prices" with the prices array, and "dates" with dates array.

##Why I've created a new object?##

Because "this.myobj" can be destructured so you can quickly and easy access to its property when you need them. So for example:

```
const {prices, dates} = this.myobj

console.log(prices, dates);
```

##Hint##:

The object returns two array of string, so if you need to work with number you need to convert elements array to number again.

##UPDATE:##

Based on The Fool comments, he is right, the performance is important, by the way is important find a compromise between performance and readability.

So my other suggestion to achive your goal is:

```
const mapper = new Map(response.prices);
const prices = Array.from(mapper.values());
const dates = Array.from(mapper.keys());

console.log(dates, prices)
```

I find this way simpler, fastest and more readable.

Comment: I dont get what you are doing there. What's that include don't and stuff all about? Why do you make the values strings and why do you filter the data?

Comment: Oh, you check if it has a don't to know if its a Unix timestamp or a prince. Why don't you just look at the index? Dates are always at index 0 and prices at index 1. You also need 4 passes, while it could be done in 1 pass.  I think It's something like O(4n^2). The length if the items is always 2 so calling it n^2 is maybe not fair or correct. But you get the point.  Additionally, converting the numbers to strings may also be expensive, and maybe you need to convert even back.  I think it tries to be to clever why it actually isn't.

Comment: Hi there, I just check if a number has dot or not, because you don't know if there are some cases where the dates are not at index 0. So to prevent this case, I've filtered for only case that is always tre, the "." In the number. By the way the question asked how to get array with prices and array with dates, and not the less expensive way to get them. How you wrote in your comment, I get the point. So why downvoted my answer? My answer provide the correct answer. I don't understand.

Comment: You know that the date will be at 0. The order matters a great deal in such an API response. You can check their docs. Apart from that, you could also make the case that you can't be sure if every price will be a decimal. What happens if something costs exaclty $1000 ? Will it be a decimal or not? In regard of perf, you should always keep it in the back of your head.